# C# Entityframework Find Item Relationships between another table when Removing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I want to when removing the item from the table in EntityFrameWork before removing show a notification that the item has relationships and if the user accepts delete remove relationship then remove the item

for example :

student table has related with addresses table(one to many) and phone Table (one to many)
when a user wants to remove a student before removing, show notify item has 2 related items "addresses", "phones"
are you sure to remove "addresses" and "phones" ?
and if the user accepted this
set null "studentId" on the addresses table and phone table

```
   var deletedItem=strudent;
   if(deletedItem.HasRelationships())
       foreach(var relation on deletedItem.GetRelationships())
            {
                 relation.findPropertybyName("studentId")=null;
            }
      db.Students.Remove(deletedItem);
```

I want to do this automatically and dynamically for all tables.
Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to run a check with `.Any(x=> x.StudentId == studentId)` both on phones and addresses.

```
    bool HasRelationships(int studentId)
    {
        return phones.Any(x=> x.StudentId == studentId) && 
                     addresses.Any(x=> x.StudentId == studentId);
    }
```

But I would suggest you avoid the additional check and just warn there might be related data. In case you get an OK, proceed with deletion.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in this way, I have to add manually all related tables, but I want to check automatically if had a related table. because maybe will be adding a new table in the future that has relation to the student table